# Cul-de-sac (curve) turns generation in flow for parallel lines using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cul-de-sac

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 and I need to generate a parallel lines within the polygon and connect them one to other with the curve, with the proper radius and return radius (the same as cul-de-sac tool propose).

I found A good solution for making a proper amount of parallel lines within the polygon here [Drawing parallel lines inside polygons (Well Paths)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114204/drawing-parallel-lines-inside-polygons-well-paths).

But still I want to use cul-de-sac tool (Advanced editing tool) in the flow to generate such turns thru all the parallel lines I create within the polygon with this script, but I couldn't find any python description how to use this.

In ArcToolbox also there just Cul-de-sac Mask tool is available.

Maybe anyone can recommend how to solve it? Maybe there is a chance to use some curve generating instruments?

[image]